# Макрос копирования данных другой книги

Tags: excel, vba

Пытаюсь сделать макрос, который будет копировать данные из одной книги (с указанием пути) в открытую книгу (где будет кнопка).

Есть код, выдает ошибку 'Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method' в строке *Sht = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")*

Как победить?

```html
Sub объем()
    'Читаем другой файл:'
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\S.Bochkarev\Desktop\ppweb2.xlsm")
    
    Sht = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Обрабатываем диапазон'
    For Counter = 1 To 20
     Set curCell = Sht.Cells(Counter, 3)
    'curCell.Value  - значение ячейки из другого файла вставляем куда надо'
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Остатки").Cells(1, 1).Value = curCell.Value
    Next Counter

    WB.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Присвоение объекта переменой - оператор `Set`

Книгу Вы разместили в переменной

```
Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\S.Bochkarev\Desktop\ppweb2.xlsm")
```

Но лист - тоже объект, нужно

```
Set Sht = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

А вот ячейка как объект не нужна, достаточно в переменную занести значение:

```
curCell = .Cells(Counter, 3).Value
```

*Application.Workbooks.Open* - открыли книгу. Нередко книга после открытия пересчитывается (наличие имен, УФ, летучих формул...). При закрытии Excel попросит подтверждения действия. Правильно - отключать сообщения:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
WB.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

После завершения работы макроса переменные очищаются, но  бывают случаи, когда память остается занятой, поэтому желательно чистить принудительно

```
    Set WB = Nothing: Set Sht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Непонятно, зачем в цикле заполнять одну ячейку (*Sheets("Остатки").Cells(1, 1).Value*) 20 раз... Бессмысленно.

Вариант. Загружать объекты в память с помощью `With`. Ячейка для вставки тоже меняется (как нужно - смотрите по задаче)

```
Sub объем()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    Set sht = TnisWorkbook.Sheets("Остатки")

    'Открываем другой файл'
    With Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\S.Bochkarev\Desktop\ppweb2.xlsm")
        With .Sheets("Sheet1")
            'Обрабатываем диапазон'
            For i = 1 To 20
                'значение ячейки из другого файла вставляем куда надо'
                sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            Next i
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
    Set sht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь тут ругается ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Остатки").Cells(3, 3).Value = curCell.Value - subscribe out of range

Comment: `subscribe out of range` - выход за пределы диапазона. Видимо, переменная не заполнена. См. код в ответе.

Comment: в строке With Application.ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With ошибка "with object must be user-defined type". Без этих строк работает. Для чего они понял, но как починить не понял)

Comment: Это получается вставляет значения начиная с А3 в столбик, а как задать кол-во столбцов?

Comment: `With Application:` было пропущено разделение строк (двоеточие). О количестве столбов не понял. Если нужно заполнять и другой столбец, добавить в цикле еще одну строку, например: `sht.Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 5).Value`

Comment: а нет ли какого-то способа объяснить, что не счетчиком брать данные, а брать данные пока не начнутся пустые ячейки? (пример: забирать все данные начиная с А3)

Comment: Вы опять все вопросы в кучу мешаете... В цикле перед заполнением ячейки создайте условие - `If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then Exit For`